# How to catch the whether the token is expired or not in machinepack-jwt

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jwt, access-token, satellizer

I use machinepack-jwt for my login and register in my project. It successfully create the token and everything goes well accept for the expiration part. I don't know how to catch if the token is expired or not. Though I put the expiration time, it is not expiring on that time. Below is my backend code for login,

```
var JWT = require('machinepack-jwt'),
    Passwords = require('machinepack-passwords'),
    GoogleAPIsOAuth2v2 = require('machinepack-googleapisoauth2v2'),
    Facebook = require('machinepack-facebook'),
    request = require('request');
   module.exports = {
    authenticate : function(req, res) {
    console.log("login");
          User.findOne({
            email: req.body.email
          }, function foundUser(err, user) {
            if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
            if (!user) return res.notFound();
    Passwords.checkPassword({
      passwordAttempt: req.body.password,
      encryptedPassword: user.password
    }).exec({
      error: function (err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.negotiate(err);
      },
      incorrect: function (){
        return res.notFound();
      },
      success: function (){
        JWT.encode({
          secret: '17ca644f4f3be572ec33711a40a5b8b4',
          payload: {
            id :  user.id,
            email:  user.email
          },
          algorithm: 'HS256',
          expires: 1
        }).exec({
          error: function (err){
            return err;
          },
          success: function (result){
            JWT.decode({
              secret: '17ca644f4f3be572ec33711a40a5b8b4',
              token : result,
              payload: {
                id :  user.id,
                email:  user.email
              },
              algorithm: 'HS256',
              expires: 1
            }).exec({
                error: function (err) {
                  res.send(err);
                },
                success: function(decodedToken){
                console.log(decodedToken);
                console.log(result);
                res.send({decodedToken,token : result, expires_in:1});
                }
            })
          }
        });
      }
    });
   });  
  }
}
```

Below is the frontend code,

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('Auth', function($http, LocalService, AccessLevels ,$auth) {
    return {
      authorize: function(access) {
        if (access === AccessLevels.user) {
          return this.isAuthenticated();
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      },
      isAuthenticated: function() {
        return $auth.isAuthenticated();
      },
      login: function(credentials) {
        var login = $http.post('/auth/authenticate', credentials);
        login.success(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
          LocalService.set('satellizer_token', result.token );
          LocalService.set('user', result.user);
        });
        return login;
      },
      logout: function() {

        LocalService.unset('satellizer_token');
      }
    }
  })
```

I want to catch if the token is expired and if expired want to redirect to the login page. How to catch if the token is expired or not?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to check the 'exp' field (expiration time) of the decoded token with the current date

```
function isExpired(exp){
    if (exp){
         return exp <= Date.now()/1000;
    } else {
         return true; //True if the token has not the expiration time field
    }
}
```

Note that in your example you are creating the token with a bad value. It must be the number of seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UT. See the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#page-9) For example an expiration time of 1 minute should be

```
exp = Date.now()/1000 + 60
```

Comment: Where should this come? in the backend?

Comment: Depend on your needs, but usually the JWT validation is done in the backend

Comment: Hi @ShamilaSallay, finally did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am putting restful service side validation here.

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
    interface Jwt {

```
        Instant getExp();

        String getAud();

        String getIss();

}
```

Decode like this

```
Jwt jwt = null;

        try {

            jwt = objectReader.readValue(payload);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new AuthenticationException(e);

        }

        // assert not expired
        if (jwt.getExp().isBefore(Instant.now())) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("auth token expired");
        }
```

Comment: This is Java. The question is about node.js and angular. Basically javascript

Comment: This kind of validation should be part of services. So, I have given restful service side validation.